# Hash & EqualTo functions for unordered_set<BSTR>

Tags: c++, windows, stl, c++17

In a code, that inserts the Windows style OLE strings (`BSTR`'s) into the good ol' STL container - the `unordered_map<BSTR>`, I declared the `unordered_set`, like this:

```
unordered_set<BSTR, std::hash<std::wstring>, std::equal_to<std::wstring>> usetBstr;
```

expecting `BSTR` strings to act like `wstring`s.

Everything seemed to work fine, until one day a `BSTR` with a zero `wchar` in the middle of the string was emplaced into the `unordered_set`.

Of course!, when the compiler converts the `BSTR` to a `std::wstring`, it stops at the first null terminator it finds in the string, because `wstring`s are not really `BSTR` strings (which keep their length in memory word immediately preceding the BSTR data and `wstring`s keep their length somewhere else).

**Question**: What `Hash` and `EqualTo` functions from the STL library would be appropriate for the `unordered_map<BSTR>` in this case?

*P.S. Of course I could roll out my own functions, but I prefer to wrap something already in the standard.*

Comment: fyi `std::wstring` is allow to have embedded zero's (it's also a counted string) so something else is going on.

Comment: Agree with @RichardCritten: `std::wstring` is already allowed to have embedded zeroes. The likely problem is that the location of the length field for `std::wstring` is different from `BSTR` (which makes sense; `BSTR` is a C type that hides it's length *before* the allocated pointer, which C++ types can't do). Point is, you're going to need to either convert your `BSTR`s to `wstring` before storing, or you'll need to write your own `hash`/`equal_to` functions that make `wstring_view`s using the `BSTR` accessors that report the real length.

Comment: @Richard Critten: The `BSTR` string gets its length from a memory word, that immediately precedes the address where the BSTR points to, but the `std::wstring` gets the length from somewhere else.

Comment: If you construct a `wstring` from a `BSTR` you'll be using the constructor that takes a `wchar_t*`, so of course it's going to stop at the first embedded NUL character. You should provide a functor for hashing a `BSTR` that takes the length prefix of the `BSTR` into account and hashes the string appropriately. Same for comparing two `BSTR`s.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I was thinking about wrapping an existing STL `Hash` and `EqualTo` functions into my own function, that would accept `BSTR` string arguments and use the `SysStringLen` function internally to calculate the length of the `BSTR`.

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson The concepts of `std::wstring` abd `bstr_t` are fundamentally different. _"Of course I could roll out my own functions, but I prefer to use something already in the standard.2_ There isn't any c++ standard that handles `bstr_t` so far. That's all proprietary with the Microsoft Windows API (primarily).

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ: Yes, look at my reply to ShadowRanger. If I calculate the length of the `BSTR` using the proprietary `SysStringLen()` and pass that length to some STL hash function that takes `wchar_t* ws` and `uint nCount` arguments, then it would be a solution.  The problem I have is finding such counted `Hash` and `EqualTo` function in the STL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with using `std::hash<std::wstring>` and `std::equal_to<std::wstring>` is that when the compiler converts the `BSTR` to a `std::wstring`, it stops at the first null terminator it finds in the string.  This means `"this\0\0"` and `"this\0"` become the same string when it hashes and checks for equality.

What you need to provide an adapter that that passes a properly construct `std::wstring`/`std::wstring_view` to the hash and equality functions.  You can do that by creating your own functors like

```
struct BSTR_hash
{
    std::size_t operator()(BSTR const& s) const noexcept
    {
        return std::hash<std::wstring_view>{}({s, SysStringLen(s)});
    }
};
struct BSTR_equal_to
{
    bool operator()(BSTR const& lhs, BSTR const& rhs) const noexcept
    {
        return std::wstring_view(lhs, SysStringLen(lhs)) == std::wstring_view(rhs, SysStringLen(rhs));
    }
};

unordered_set<BSTR, BSTR_hash, BSTR_equal_to> usetBstr;
```

Comment: Is converting to `std::wstring_view` very costly? e.g. copying the entire string in memory?

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson No it is not.  The view has a pointer and a size, no actual string data is copied.

Comment: Good. It is a nice solution, then :)